# Node failed to start! HazelCast

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, configuration, hazelcast

`
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/prospecta/mdo/notification/config/MultiTenantDatasourceConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.cache.spi.CacheImplementor]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:765) ~[spring-boot-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:445) ~[spring-boot-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.7.jar:2.5.7]
at com.prospecta.mdo.notification.MdoNotificationApplication.main(MdoNotificationApplication.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.cache.spi.CacheImplementor]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.cache.spi.CacheImplementor]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.getService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:246) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cache provider not started
at org.hibernate.cache.spi.AbstractRegionFactory.verifyStarted(AbstractRegionFactory.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.cache.spi.support.RegionFactoryTemplate.buildTimestampsRegion(RegionFactoryTemplate.java:66) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.cache.internal.EnabledCaching.(EnabledCaching.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:33) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:24) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.spi.SessionFactoryServiceInitiator.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceInitiator.java:30) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Node failed to start!
at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.HazelcastInstanceImpl.(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:125) ~[hazelcast-4.1.6.jar:4.1.6]
at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:211) ~[hazelcast-4.1.6.jar:4.1.6]
at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:190) ~[hazelcast-4.1.6.jar:4.1.6]
at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:128) ~[hazelcast-4.1.6.jar:4.1.6]
at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:57) ~[hazelcast-4.1.6.jar:4.1.6]
at com.hazelcast.hibernate.instance.HazelcastInstanceLoader.loadInstance(HazelcastInstanceLoader.java:79) ~[hazelcast-hibernate53-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
at com.hazelcast.hibernate.AbstractHazelcastCacheRegionFactory.prepareForUse(AbstractHazelcastCacheRegionFactory.java:147) ~[hazelcast-hibernate53-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
at org.hibernate.cache.spi.AbstractRegionFactory.start(AbstractRegionFactory.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.cache.internal.EnabledCaching.(EnabledCaching.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
... 33 common frames omitted

`

Propeties file

spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ANT_PATH_MATCHER

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true

spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode=ENABLE_SELECTIVE

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=com.hazelcast.hibernate.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory

My application is not getting up

Comment: Even doing second level cache to false,  not resolving the issue

Answer (score 0):

My guess is there is a version conflict. You seem to be using **hazelcast-4.1.6** according to exception stack trace

This pom.xml works for me. It should bring in hazelcast **5.X**. Just make sure that you are **not using** hazelcast **4.X** somehow

```xml
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.3</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

And

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
  <artifactId>hazelcast-hibernate53</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```